# jquery if contains text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making a log-in/off button using asp MVC 5  I have it set up so that the Session["isLoggedIn"] will show a different text if someone is logged in or not.

Now i need to code the JQuery to add an href to the login pages or logout respectively.

This is my Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#loginLogoff").text("sign out"))
            $("#loginLogoff").attr("href", "javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()");
        else 
            $("#loginLogoff").attr("href", "/Home#login_popup");
    });
</script>
```

I can get it to change to the logout page upon load. However it doesn't ever fire the else statement 
 I have tried different keywords, all to no avail

```
.val()
.text()
.html()
```

html block looks like this in c#

```
<li style="padding-top:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>@Session["LoginStatus"]</strong> | <a id="loginLogoff" style="display:inline;"> @Session["logInOffToggle"]</a></li>
```

and in formatted html

```
<li style="padding-top:10px;text-align:right;"><strong>not Logged In</strong> | <a id="loginLogoff" style="display:inline;"> Login</a></li>
```

Comment: `if ($("#loginLogoff").text() === "sign out")` ?! Using `$("#loginLogoff").text("sign out")` you are assigning it and btw this  returns jQuery object and then condition is always true

Comment: Since you are already using razor, why not add the link through razor ?

Answer (score 2):

The Else-Block is never run, because the jQuery method .text("String") sets the text of the result list it is called upon and returns the same result list. So in your case this is always true, since a not empty list evalutes to true.

You want to use the .text() method without an argument to get the text.

You should change your condition like so:

```
if ( $("#loginLogoff").text() === "sign out" ) {
    ...
}
```